# Loading React component from another file

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-router, material-ui

I am using the React Material-UI library. I have a search 'filter' on the main/parent page, which should pop open a Drawer that is located in a separate file.

I understand how this all works within one file, but I cannot understand how to break this into separate files (obviously for code clarity intent). I also cannot tell how I get the 'variables' out of the Drawer for items I select. Below I have pasted my two files, whereby I would like to get the 'onclick' in the parent to launch the Drawer in the child file. Any assistance would be excellent!

My parent file:

```html
return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="search"
      ...
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Search for an item"
          variant="outlined"
          InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="start">
                <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="filters" component="span">
                  <TuneRoundedIcon onClick={ handleFilterOpen } />
                </IconButton>
                <Filter open={ openFilter} />
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            endAdornment: (
              <React.Fragment>
                {loading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} /> : null}
                {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
              </React.Fragment>
            ),
          }}
          fullWidth
        />
      )}
```

And this is the Filter.tsx (my child file):

```html
export default function Filter() {
const classes = useStyles();
const theme = useTheme();
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
   setOpen(true);
};

const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
};

return (
<Drawer
    className={classes.drawer}
    variant="persistent"
    anchor="right"
    open={open}
    classes={{
      paper: classes.drawerPaper,
    }}
  >
    <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
      <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
        {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : <ChevronRightIcon />}
      </IconButton>
    </div>
    <Divider />
    <List>
      {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
        <ListItem button key={text}>
          <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={text} />
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
    <Divider />
    <List>
      {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
        <ListItem button key={text}>
          <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={text} />
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
  </Drawer>
);
}
```

Comment: This is some basic react stuff. the parent component handles the open state and passes it as a prop to the child component. the child component doesn't have an "open" state, instead it uses the open prop variable passed from above

Comment: I am certain it is basic, but I only started with React a week ago ;-). Sorry, I get what you're saying but can't quite fit it into the code calls...

Comment: Apologies... To add, I also don't quite get how a selected variable (e.g. toggle switch) would be pulled back from child to parent... Again, simply new to this, so it doesn't map well in my head when the files are split.

Comment: I added an answer to your question. I hope this suits your needs, if not feel free to ask further questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the open state down to the child component via props. The child component should not have an "open" state. I've simplified this for you for better understanding:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const toggleOpen = () => {
     setOpen(!open)
  }
  
  const customFunction(valueFromChildComponent) {
    alert(valueFromChildComponent); // this alerts "myValue" since "myValue" is passed from child component
  }
  
  return (
    <Child isOpen={open} myCustomFunction={customFunction} />
  );  
}
```

Child component

```
const Child = props => {      
  return (
    console.log(props.isOpen) // props.isOpen contains the value passed down from the parent
    <button onClick={props.myCustomFunction("myValue")}>test Button</button>
  );  
}
```

I've also added an example how you could pass up a value form your child component. in my case i passed up a string but you could for example pass up the selected value of a drop down or basically whatever you want.